# Error:(155) Original attribute defined here, in Android Studio 2.3.1

Tags: android, android-studio

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])

```
compile 'com.android.support:design:25.3.1'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:25.3.1'
compile 'com.android.support:preference-v7:25.3.1'
compile 'com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305:3.0.0'
compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.6.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:7.0.0'
compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.0'
compile 'com.android.volley:volley:1.0.0'
compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.7.0'
compile 'ch.acra:acra:4.9.2'
compile 'com.github.yukuku:ambilwarna:2.0.1'
compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.0-alpha7'


testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```

This is gradle dependencies code. I am getting such type of errors.
When i click on this error then code is showing .cannot find decleration of element 'recources'.
    D:\AndroidProjects\Tech\app\build\intermediates\res\merged\debug\values\values.xml
    Error:(360) Attribute "navigationMode" already defined with incompatible format.

```
Error:(155) Original attribute defined here.

Error:(367) Attribute "displayOptions" already defined with incompatible format.

Error:(687) Attribute "backgroundTintMode" already defined with incompatible format.

Error:(367) Attribute "displayOptions" already defined with incompatible format.

Error:(360) Attribute "navigationMode" already defined with incompatible format.

Error:(419) Attribute "actionBarSize" already defined with incompatible format.

Error:(70) Original attribute defined here.

Error:(482) Attribute "buttonTintMode" already defined with incompatible format.

Error:(7) Original attribute defined here.

Error:(102) Original attribute defined here.

Error:(576) Attribute "showDividers" already defined with incompatible format.

Error:(360) Attribute "navigationMode" already defined with incompatible format.

Error:(184) Original attribute defined here.

Error:(601) Attribute "showAsAction" already defined with incompatible format.

Error:(191) Original attribute defined here.

Error:(52) Original attribute defined here.

Error:(155) Original attribute defined here.

Error:(102) Original attribute defined here.

Error:(419) Attribute "actionBarSize" already defined with incompatible format.

Error:(7) Original attribute defined here.

Error:(482) Attribute "buttonTintMode" already defined with incompatible format.

Error:(70) Original attribute defined here.

Error:(576) Attribute "showDividers" already defined with incompatible format.

Error:(191) Original attribute defined here.

Error:(601) Attribute "showAsAction" already defined with incompatible format.

Error:(184) Original attribute defined here.

Error:(687) Attribute "backgroundTintMode" already defined with incompatible format.

Error:(52) Original attribute defined here.

Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.
> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: Failed to execute aapt
```

Comment: If you press the warnings in Android Studio it will most likely take you to the line where the error occured. Copy the entire file where you are taken to (if you are taken to a file) into your question

Comment: after adding dependency you are getting these errors?

Comment: Yes this error is coming after adding dependencies -Kriti

Comment: Thanks @LunarWatcher but i am able to copy entire code because code too large.

Comment: I solved my problem.I changed these attributes 'displayOptions',"backgroundTintMode","navigationMode","actionBarSize","showAsAction".These attributes name should be changed in attrs.xml file.I ranamed these attributes.After that my problem was solved.

Answer (score -1):

You have the same property name as the other controls, and modify the name of the property of your custom control.